# Get values from dynamic object array

Tags: javascript

Hello In Javascript I get error result from API result array object can be

```
{
   ProjectName:["Invalid Project Name"],
   entityName:["Invalid entityName"]

}
```

or

```
{
   ProjectName:["Invalid Project Name"],
    
}
```

and key names are dynamic which comes from API. so I just need values as

```
["Invalid Project Name","Invalid entityName"]
```

How can I convert this object to this array ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use object values

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var errors = [];
var obj = {
  ProjectName: ["Invalid Project Name"],
  entityName: ["Invalid entityName"],
};
Object.keys(obj).map((k) => {
  obj[k].map((x) =>
    errors.push({
      key: k,
      message: x,
    })
  );
});

errors.map(k => {
  console.log("Check " + k.key + " field: " + k.message)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` method with `reduce`

```js
const obj = {
   ProjectName:["Invalid Project Name"],
   entityName:["Invalid entityName"]
}
const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, curr) => {
   prev.push(obj[curr][0]);
   return prev;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) combined with map and flat:

```js
var obj = {
  ProjectName: ["Invalid Project Name"],
  entityName: ["Invalid entityName"],
};
console.log(Object.values(obj).map(i => i).flat())
```